# Ansible breaking templates with quotes around variables when more than one on same line

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm using an Ansible template to include variables in a SQL import file, and everything was working fine until lately where ansible is now parsing the quotes around variables in the template and eliminating some of them, where it never used to.

For example, the following...

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1, '{{ var.one }}', NULL, '{{ var.two }}');
```

...is now resulting in...

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1, 'value-one, NULL, value-two');
```

Notice that the two single quotes in the middle have been removed.  This breaks the SQL.  As per the MySQL/ANSI standards, I'm supposed to be using single quotes for string literals, and backticks only for identifiers.  So what's the solution here?  And does anyone know when this behaviour changed?

I'm using Ansible 2.9.27

---

As requested, here is the simple template task call...

```
- name: Copy SQL Dynamic Data Dump File for import
  template: src=data.sql.j2 dest=/tmp/data.sql
```

Comment: You should provide a full working example of this. Including an Ansible task

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε It's a simple ansible template task no magic, I've recently had to make the same changes to some of the `json_query` statements for the same reason, though there it was easier to fix with backticks which are treated as literals.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I've added an answer which points to the known bug(s) causing this issue.

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre] would be #SOreadytohelp (with the focus on minimal).

Comment: You say: ``'the highest version available in many distros is 2.9'``. Which distros are you talking about?

Comment: @VladimirBotka RHEL / CentOS / Rocky / Cloud / etc.

Answer (score 1):

This [issue has already been solved](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76761#issuecomment-1013291491). The example below works for me both in 2.10 and 2.12

- ansible [core 2.12.1], python 3.8.5, jinja 3.0.1
- ansible 2.10.11, python 3.6.9, python3-jinja2 2.10-1ubuntu0.18.04.1

```sh
shell> cat import.sql.j2
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, '{{ var.one }}', NULL, '{{ var.two }}');
```

and the task

```yaml
     - template:
         src: import.sql.j2
         dest: import.sql
       vars:
         var:
           one: value-one
           two: value-two
```

give valid SQL

```sql
shell> cat import.sql
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'value-one', NULL, 'value-two');
```

---

As a workaround put the single quote into the expression

```sh
shell> cat import.sql.j2
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, {{ "'" }}{{ var.one }}{{ "'" }}, NULL, {{ "'" }}{{ var.two }}{{ "'" }});
```

---

Use sed to make these changes globally, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat templates/import.sql.j2
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, '{{ var.one }}', NULL, '{{ var.two }}');
```

```sh
shell> for i in templates/*; do sed -i "s/'/{{ \"'\" }}/g" $i; done
```

```sh
shell> cat templates/import.sql.j2
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, {{ "'" }}{{ var.one }}{{ "'" }}, NULL, {{ "'" }}{{ var.two }}{{ "'" }});
```

Optionally choose a linter and validate SQL. The *validate* option in the *template* module doesn't work for *sqlfluff* hence the next *command* task is used below. The testing of the line length is excluded (*--exclude-rules L016*).

```yaml
    - template:
        src: import.sql.j2
        dest: import.sql
      register: result
      vars:
        var:
          one: value-one
          two: value-two
    - command: "sqlfluff lint {{ result.dest }}  --exclude-rules L016"
      changed_when: false
```

Comment: Sorry but this is misleading...  First, you're pointing at MY bug report that I filed with Ansible, and which I included in my self-answer here, along with the root issue bug report for Jinja2.  More importantly, the issue was solved in Jinja 2.11, however it's Ansible that is causing the issue to continue to present in Jinja 3.0.3 as I indicated in the bug report.  It will NOT be fixed in Ansible 2.9, but as you point out IS fixed in Ansible 2.11.  That said, the highest version available in many distros is 2.9 which will only get security patches.

Comment: Ansible 2.9 is [End of Life since December 31, 2021](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine).

Comment: Community releases Ansible 2.9 and 2.10 are [Expected end of Life May 2022](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-changelogs). It's time to upgrade and start testing at least in development.

Comment: Easier said than done, max version in RHEL / CentOS / Rocky / Cloud, and any other Fedora forks are all 2.9.

Comment: As a workaround put the single quote into the expression. I added the example.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, that solution is ok for one or two instances, but in our case, we have a SQL dump file where there are sometimes a dozen vars per line and hundreds of records.  This solution would be untenable sadly. It was suggested in the Bug report as well as a quick fix, and I tested it earlier but found it would be far too much work to have to work around something that is obviously a bug.

Comment: Use *sed* to make changes globally. I added the example. Make sure you have a good backup.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is related to a known bug in Jinja2 that was fixed in 2.11.  I'm using 3.0.3 though so it's odd that its still a problem, so I launched a bug report with Ansible and they've confirmed the behaviour.  The way Jinja2 Native is used in templating has changed in Ansible 2.11 which should alieviate the problem, however until it's available in the release channel for our distro, we've been able to fix the problem by disabling "native" support in Jinja2 which we were using.  This may cause other problems, but we're stuck since Ansible 2.9 is only receiving security patches now.

My Bug report is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76761

The Jinja2 Bug report is here: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/1020

Comment: This is basically why I never install Ansible with the package manager which systematically carries dinosaur aged versions for this particular package. My 2 cent: uninstall the current yum/dnf/apt... version and `pip install ansible`

Comment: @Zeitounator I would agree but Rocky 8.5 has a max of Pip 9.0.3, and Ansible 2.9.27 both in the distro packages AND via Pip.  One of the downsides of not going with a more progressive distro, but I've never had a stability issue in production for 10+ years.  Win some lose some.

Comment: You can upgrade pip as a user in your own environment without overriding the distro one  and install ansible there.